# reportlab svg2rlg draws image with border

Tags: svg, reportlab

Reportlab (3.5.42) is now drawing a border around my SVG image where it did not a few months ago.
I tried downgrading to previous versions of ReportLab with no luck.
Even an old SVG still gets rendered with a border. How do I get rid of the border?
Here's a sample:

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

c = Canvas('sample.pdf')
otb = svg2rlg('sample.svg')
x = 5 * inch
y = 5 * inch
renderPDF.draw(otb, c, x=x, y=y)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

[Here's the SVG.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B9ztzaDcqrji0M7t6m76SkRVHETRFD87/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Answer that worked for me at this time: downgrade to svglib 0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the bug described in https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/238 and is supposed to be fixed in svglib 1.0.1 according to the [change log](https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#101-2020-08-26).

I am experiencing a similar problem which does not happen when I use 0.9.0, but unfortunately it still happens with both 1.0.1 and 1.1.0 in my case.